# Tkinter, xlwt, Trying to edit checkbuttons that have been created in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

This is part of my code for a register in tkinter which also uses xlwt,xlutils and xlrd (Excel modules). It takes the names from a file and creates a list of these names with 'present' checkbuttons next to them:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FC4p.jpg

I want to save the checkbuttons' on and off values so that i can put them in the excel spreadsheet but because i've created them in a loop the variable will be the same for all of them and therefore if i add that and click on them, they all switch on and off.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
    x=0
    y=1
    for line in open(register,"r"):
        with open(register,"r") as file:
            all_lines=file.readlines()
        Label(registersuccess,text=all_lines[x].strip("\n")).grid(column=0,row=x)
        Checkbutton(registersuccess,text="Present").grid(column=1,row=x)
        listeesheet.write(x,0,all_lines[x].strip("\n"))

        entrysheet.write(y,0,all_lines[x].strip("\n"))
        entrywb.save(filename)
        x=x+1
        y=y+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to save a the value of a checkbutton outside of a loop it would look like so:

```py
present = tk.IntVar()
tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Present", variable=present)
```

This creates a new [Tkinter Variable](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), which when the checkbutton is pressed it is equal to 1, and when it is unchecked it is equal to 0 (these can be changed with the parameters `offvalue` and `onvalue`.

If we want to do the same within a loop we will place all the checkbutton variables into a dictionary, like so:

```py
import tkinter as tk # recommended over the use of "from tkinter import *"
root = tk.Tk()

def get_present():
    for name, present in register_dict.items(): # searches through the dictionary, and puts the persons name into the variable name and the checkbutton variable into the present variable
        print(name, present.get()) # present.get() gets the current value of a tkinter variable

register = "names.txt" # Use your own text file
with open(register,"r") as file: # moved outside of the loop to prevent the system reloading the file every time - saves time
        all_lines=file.readlines()
registersuccess = tk.Frame(root) # Use your own registersuccess Frame/Window
registersuccess.grid(row=0, column=0)
x=0
y=1
register_dict = {} # creates an empty dictionary 
for line in open(register,"r"): # for each line in the register
    name = all_lines[x].strip("\n") # get the current name and remove the enter key

    tk.Label(registersuccess,text=name).grid(column=0,row=x) # Add a label with the name
    register_dict[name] = tk.IntVar() # places into the register dictionary the key: name, and a new integer  
    tk.Checkbutton(registersuccess,text="Present", variable=register_dict[name]).grid(column=1,row=x) # on a checkbutton change the variable will be updated accordingly

    x += 1 # A more python way to write x = x + 1
    y += 1

tk.Button(registersuccess, command=get_present, text="Print Present").grid(column=0, row=x, rowspan=2) # Prints the values (can be removed for your project)
root.mainloop()
```

This code can be further optimised by, instead of reopening the file, use the list `all lines`:

```py
for line in all_lines:
    name = line.strip("\n")
```

The timings on my machine after this look like this:

```
$ python3 optimized.py
real    0m0.312s
user    0m0.073s
sys     0m0.013s
$ python3 unoptimized.py
real    0m0.318s
user    0m0.059s
sys     0m0.030s
```

The import numbers to look at in this are the length of time it takes for the user to see the effect and the amount of `sys time` (the optimised code being nearly 3x faster)